Querying Json_Object_t using dot notation in Oracle 19c
I have a case where Json document is passed as CLOB input to a stored procedure.
I am converting it into Json Object as below
l_js_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T(p_js_clob_i);
Json:
{"Key1":{"Key2":{"Key3": "Val3"}}}

I am able to access particular key-value using below code
l_js_obj.get _object('key1').get_object('key2').get_string('key3');

By storing this CLOB into a column in a table, I am able to access the json using dot notation
Select t.column.key1.key2.key3 From t;

My question is, is it possible to access JSON_OBJECT_T using dot notation in Oracle 19?


Is it possible to access JSON_OBJECT_T using dot notation in Oracle 19?

No, if you try:
DECLARE
  l_js_obj JSON_OBJECT_T
    := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE('{"Key1":{"Key2":{"Key3": "Val3"}}}');
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_js_obj.Key1.Key2.Key3);
END;
/

You get the exception:

ORA-06550: line 5, column 33:
PLS-00302: component 'KEY1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


Since the JSON_OBJECT_T does not have methods named for its keys.

Interpreting your question slightly differently, no again, if you want to use dot notation within the methods that JSON_OBJECT_T does have to try and get nested objects with a single method call.
l_js_obj.get_string('Key1.Key2.Key3') means get the value for the key "Key1.Key2.Key3" and does not mean to get the value for the "Key3" key nested inside an object containing the "Key2" key nested inside an object containing the "Key1" key.
You can see the difference using:
DECLARE
  l_js_obj JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(
                              '{
                                 "Key1":{"Key2":{"Key3": "Val3"}},
                                 "Key1.Key2.Key3": "Val123"
                               }'
                            );
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    l_js_obj.get_object('Key1').get_object('Key2').get_string('Key3')
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    l_js_obj.get_string('Key1.Key2.Key3')
  );
END;
/

Which outputs:

Val3
Val123


It is the same as using the query:
SELECT t.value.Key1.Key2.Key3,
       t.value."Key1.Key2.Key3"
FROM   table_name t

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value JSON CHECK (value IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES ('{
  "Key1":{"Key2":{"Key3": "Val3"}},
  "Key1.Key2.Key3": "Val123"
}');

Outputs:



KEY1
Key1.Key2.Key3




"Val3"
"Val123"



You are not getting nested keys but are getting a key that contains the . character.
fiddle
